# I cant change my form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have big problem. I have 2 forms in my VB.NET project. The names of Forms are Form1 and Form2. I have a button with this codes:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    Dim Login As New Form2
    Login.Show()
End Sub
```

Now when I click in this button Form2 will open, but after 3 or 4 minutes Form1 will open again.
I should say Me.close() to same happen with Me.Hide() for me.

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fff As New Form2
    fff.Close()
    Form3.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MsgBox("Sorry", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxHelp, "Error")
End Sub
```

I need help please

Comment: There's nothing in this code that will re-display the current form or create/show a new instance of the current form's type.

Comment: form1 is showing up again because you have code somewhere to show it

Comment: Can you provide the code for `Form2`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Login As New Form2
Form2.Show()
Me.dispose()
End Sub
```

it should solve the problem

Comment: Sorry bro but its same as other

Comment: can u copas full script Form1,Form2,Form3?